# Grouping XML elements in Swift

Tags: xml, swift

I've got an array of CGPoints (and, of course, their x/y coordinates). I'm trying to create and export xml structure to a file but I can't arrange the elements properly. I need to group cgpoints by four and then add source element at the end of each group (with closing map tag). Like this:

```
<map>
   <point id="1" top="0" left="0"/>
   <point id="2" top="0" left="532"/>
   <point id="3" top="211" left="532"/>
   <point id="4" top="211" left="0"/>
   <source image="mix" top="0" left="0" width="532" height="211"/>
</map>
<map>
   <point id="5" top="0" left="532"/>
   <point id="6" top="0" left="686"/>
   <point id="7" top="211" left="686"/>
   <point id="8" top="211" left="532"/>
   <source image="mix" top="0" left="532" width="154" height="211"/>
</map>
```

But result I'm getting, looks like this:

```
<map>
   <point id="1" top="0" left="0"/>
   <point id="2" top="0" left="532"/>
   <point id="3" top="211" left="532"/>
   <point id="4" top="211" left="0"/>
   <point id="5" top="0" left="532"/>
   <point id="6" top="0" left="686"/>
   <point id="7" top="211" left="686"/>
   <point id="8" top="211" left="532"/>
   <source image="mix" top="0" left="532" width="154" height="211"/>
</map>
```

What do I do wrong? Here is a code:

```
   let map = NSXMLElement(name: "map")

   let array = myArray.flatMap { return $0.myCoord() }  
      for (ind, dot) in array.enumerate() {  
         let x1 = dot.x
         let y1 = dot.y

   let point = NSXMLElement(name: "point")
        point.attributes = [
            xmlAttributeWithName("id", value: "\(ind+1)"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("top", value: "\(Int(x1))"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("left", value: "\(Int(y1))")
        ]
        map.addChild(point)
    }

    let source = NSXMLElement(name: "source")
        source.attributes = [
            xmlAttributeWithName("image", value: "mix"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("top", value: "\(Int(x1))"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("left", value: "\(Int(y1))"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("width", value: "\(Int(x3))"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("height", value: "\(Int(y3))")
        ]
        map.addChild(source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest 2 loops together. The outer loop should step by 4, the inner loop steps by 1 and correspond to each `map` element:

```
let root = NSXMLElement(name: "root")

for i in 0.stride(to: array.count, by: 4) {
    let map = NSXMLElement(name: "map")

    for j in i..<(i + 4) {
        let point = NSXMLElement(name: "point")

        point.attributes = [
            xmlAttributeWithName("id", value: "\(j)"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("top", value: "\(Int(array[j].y))"),
            xmlAttributeWithName("left", value: "\(Int(array[j].x))")
        ]
        map.addChild(point)
    }

    let source = NSXMLElement(name: "source")
    source.attributes = [
        xmlAttributeWithName("image", value: "mix"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("top", value: "\(Int(array[i+2].y))"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("left", value: "\(Int(array[i].x))"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("width", value: "\(Int(array[i+3].x))"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("height", value: "\(Int(array[i+1].y))")
    ]
    map.addChild(source)
    root.addChild(map)
}

print(root)
```

(this assumes are `array` has length that's divisible by 4)

Comment: I made my code the same as yours but there is an error: Assertion failure in -[NSXMLElement insertChild:atIndex:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1259/XML.subproj/XMLTypes.subproj/NSXMLElement.m:915.
[2162:115322] Cannot add a child that has a parent; detach or copy first.

Comment: ... and if I add **root** instead of **root.addChild(map)**, </map> appears beneath all groups of points.

Comment: I fixed it. Everything works as expected. That was my error. Thnx)